# Why ng-selected call the function n-Times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to call a function from a selectbox by click on a item.

**HTML TAG**

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3><small>Organiser</small></h3>
    <input type="text" id="#tournament-organiser-name" ng-model="organiserName" class="form-control" name="organisert-name" ng-keyup="findOrganiser(organiserName)" />

    <div class="form-group btn-toolbar-bottom" ng-hide="searchResultshow" ng-model="searchResultshow">
        <select class="form-control" size="3"  name="singleSelect" height="40px" id="singleSelect" ng-model="organiserLikeList" >
          <option ng-repeat="option in organiserLikeList" ng-value="{{option.id}}" ng-selected="selectOrganiser(option)">{{option.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.selectOrganiser = function(x){
  console.log(x);
}
```

I've try to change the directive.

The parameter should be a field from the `organsierLikeList`. But it does not work.

**ng-click** :
The function is does not call.

**ng-selected**: The function is called n times (Seems two time for each )

Something is strange to me:

I when I enter one letter into the textfield, the function is called, but the ng-selected directive is on the option-Tag in the select-Tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind click event to individual option elements. Instead subscribe to onchange event of the entire selectbox:

```
<div class="form-group btn-toolbar-bottom" ng-hide="searchResultshow">
    <select class="form-control" size="3" name="singleSelect" height="40px" id="singleSelect" 
            ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in organiserLikeList"
            ng-change="selectOrganiser()"
            ng-model="organiserSelected">
    </select>
</div>
```

Also, make use of ngOptions instead of ngRepeat.

Comment: Also, take a look at the documentation for ngSelected: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: @dfsq : THX for the fast response.  I have changed the line  from `ng-change="selectOrganiser(option)" `  to `ng-change="selectOrganiser(organiserLikeList)" `, then the id from the Object is given to the function. But the function keeps calling two times. At the first call the result of the `console.info(x)` is the `id` and the second result is `undefined`.

Comment: @mammut Yea, there is another problem. Change ngModel to something, you don't want to redefine `organiserLikeList`. Then inside of `selectOrganiser` access selected option as `$scope.organiserSelected`. http://plnkr.co/edit/RGqtFPwiqNe8VdGBm0yP?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Template

```
<select class="form-control" size="3"  name="singleSelect" height="40px" id="singleSelect" ng-model="selectOption" >
    <option ng-repeat="option in organiserLikeList" value="{{option}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
$scope.$watch("selectOption", function(newval, oldval){
    var newval_ = JSON.parse(newval);
    alert(newval_.id);
});
```

see this link https://plnkr.co/edit/SPiv8EzbWdvKsGgda5es?p=preview